# preserve value of hidden variable over round trips

Tags: asp.net, state-management

I need to maintain a unique identifier over server round trips. This is applicable for any pages in the website. Hence the value of the unique identifier is stored inside a from in a hidden variable in the application master page.

What is the best way to preserve this value over round trips? I am using ASP.net

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean that the hidden variable is a value of some hidden field?

Comment: If you put the value in hidden field, it will be maintained during postback. What is the specific issue you are getting?

Comment: Sorry, yes its the value in a hidden form field.

Comment: @Muhammad: I want to preserve the value during all round trips, for e.g. link navigation, browser back and forward buttons etc.

Comment: is it not maintained currently in hidden field, I think it should be maintainded

Answer (score 1):

Store value in Session and set value of the HiddenField on the first time page loaded:

```
private string MyUniqiueId
    {
        get { return Session["MyUniqiueId"] as string; }
        set { Session["MyUniqiueId"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            MyUniqiueIdHiddenField.Value = MyUniqiueId;
        }
    }
```